# Supporting Add to homescreen apps for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Is it possible to add the meta tags

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

to the Stack Exchange web pages? With these meta tags it would be possible to put a shortcut to the landing page for any Stack Exchange site to the Android or iPhone home screen and having the web application run in full-screen mode (without having the browser control and the address bar visible).

Find more information at:

- https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
- https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html